# Auto scale on IOS devices

Tags: html

I want to disable auto-scaling feature of ios but It disables ability to zoom the page for android devices

I have tried this meta tag:

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Auto-scaling is disabled in safari, and user with IOS device can zoom the page, but now, zooming not worked on android devices.
I can't find solution which fits my needs.
Maybe there is an option which will force meta to work only on IOS devices ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can we see more of your html? can't help blind.

Comment: I have already edited the question.

Comment: I don't think there is `user-agent` attribute for `meta`, at least not in docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta